# Married Filing Separately - Who Can Deduct Mortgage Interest

Tags: united-states, taxes, mortgage, tax-deduction

Wife and I are married, but filing separately due to excessive student loans that she has.  Mortgage is in my name (due to excessive student loans that she has), but we are both on the title of the house.

We paid ~6k in interest on the house.  It's less than the standard deduction and I have no other deductions.  Declaring it on my taxes (as I understand it) would not benefit me at all.

Because the mortgage was accessible via my account when logged into the site, I made all of the payments from my account.  But my wife and have similar incomes and share all of our expenses.

Can she deduct none of/all of/half of the amount of interest we paid?  Next year, should she pay 100% of the mortgage payments, while I simply pay for other things the IRS doesn't care about to maximize our legal deductions?

Comment: Just curious, but why does her having large student loans make it better to file separately?

Comment: If she's not paying her student loans back, tax refund garnishment could be one reason.

Comment: Typical deductions when you have a mortgage and want to itemize: property tax, state income tax, charity.

Comment: If your wife is not listed on the mortgage, it is not her debt, and she is not eligible to deduct any of the mortgage interest, even if she paid all of it out of her personal account (one on which you are not a joint owner). Property tax is levied on the property and so she and you are both liable for it, but not the mortgage interest.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Doesn't that depend on the state (and its community property laws)?

Comment: IANAL, but I'd expect that since it's only your name on the loan, only you can deduct the interest.

Comment: My understanding is that spouses filing separately are free to allocate expenses and the corresponding deduction as they see fit. They *must* both itemize, of course. See [here](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/deduct-home-mortgage-interest-filing-separately-50283.html) for one example.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The example that you link to implicitly assumes that both spouses are jointly the mortgagees, the most common scenario. Here, the wife is specifically not the mortgagee, and Form 1098 reporting the mortgage interest paid has only the husband's name on it. So it is not clear why the spouse can take the deduction. It is not her debt.

Comment: @DilipSarwate It should be clear -- she paid it (especially if in a State where she was legally obligated to pay it). Unfortunately, the IRS seems to disagree: "However, if only one of you is eligible for a deduction for an expense (for example, real estate taxes on a property owned only by the eligible spouse), only the spouse who is eligible for the deduction is allowed to claim it, even if the expense is paid from joint funds. Each spouse must maintain records documenting who is considered to have paid the expense."

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Err no; in this case the wife didn't pay the mortgage interest at all. The OP says "Because the mortgage was accessible via my account when logged into the site, I made all of the payments from _my_ account." (emphasis added).

Comment: @DilipSarwate That depends on the State. Sure, he made the payments from his account, but he may have used money that was just as much hers as his.

Comment: @DStanley - As it was explained to me, for people who are making income based repayments (IBR/ICR) or who are participating in the public service loan forgiveness (which has payments based on income), depending on the state, when filing separately, only the income of the borrower will be used in the calculation.

Comment: Having said that, I really don't know what I'm talking about.  So take that as potentially wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, let's make sure we clear up one issue.  If your spouse is itemizing deductions, you *must* also (or, rather, if you don't, you won't get any benefit - you won't get the standard deduction).  See this [IRS FAQ answer on itemizing when filing separately](https://www.irs.gov/help-resources/tools-faqs/faqs-for-individuals/frequently-asked-tax-questions-answers/itemized-deductions-standard-deduction/other-deduction-questions/other-deduction-questions).

Second, the issue of whether your wife is permitted to deduct any of it is complex, and may suggest professional advice if it's worth it monetarily.  The IRS has a few rules for deducting mortgage interest, all listed in [publication 936](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p936/ar02.html), summarized here:

- You must itemize and use Form 1040
- The mortgage must be a secured debt, on a qualified home, in which you have an ownership interest
- You, or your spouse if filing *jointly*, must have taken out the loan
- You must have incurred the expense yourself (i.e., paid it)
- Additionally, there are some income, funds use, and mortgage balance requirements likely not relevant here.

I think the third point is a sticky point for you: you, and not her, are on the loan, and you're filing separately.  The fourth point may be relevant also, depending on whether you're in a community property state or not (and depending on some other details).

As such, it seems likely that she may not deduct the mortgage interest.

But further, it sounds like you shouldn't either.  If you truly don't have any other significant deductions, beyond presumably state income tax and property tax, it's possible that you may both be better off not itemizing.

For example, let's say your joint potential deductions are the interest ($6000), which is 4.5% on a $150k mortgage on a $180k home.  Looking at [property taxes](https://wallethub.com/edu/states-with-the-highest-and-lowest-property-taxes/11585/), the median (25th state) is about 1% effective rate, so another $1800.  Then your income tax - let's say you make $120000 jointly after the normal above-line deductions etc., and you live in a state like Missouri which seems to be about average according to the [Tax Foundation](https://taxfoundation.org/state-individual-income-tax-rates-and-brackets-2016/) with a 6% tax rate; simplifying things, you pay .06*120000 = $7200.

So your total deductions are $15000 ($6000+$7200+$1800).  That's over the amount you'll get as the standard deduction ($12600), but not by that much.  It's well possible you live in somewhere like Illinois (3.75%, so $4500; $12300 total) where it's better not to itemize.

Though this also assumes your incomes are more or less equivalent; of course, if she makes $90k and you make $30k, or the reverse, you have a different equation - but that can go both ways.  If you're the one who would itemize the $6000 interest, and she has the higher income, for example, you may end up in a situation where you can deduct $10500 and her $4500, which would be bad for your overall taxes.

So - all in all, you are probably the one to do the interest deduction (but talk to a tax professional if you're unsure and it makes a big monetary difference), and consider if taking the standard deduction might be better for you two (and remember that you both have to make the same choice there).

Comment: I think that it is worth emphasizing the third and fourth points with respect to the wife of the OP. _She_ did not take out the loan (her name is not on the mortgage) and since the spouses are filing separately, she cannot take advantage of the "(or your spouse, if filing jointly)" exception; and she did not incur the expense herself since the husband paid the interest out of an account of which she is not a joint owner(as far as we know).